# Good third-party analytics for tracking page views through URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, language-agnostic

I have users in my app, and to put it simple, each user has many pictures. These pictures are viewed somewhere else - not on my website (my website is only for managing them - creating, deleting, showing views stats etc). On the other websites they are shown simply like so:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/mypicture_132.png" />
```

And each time someone opens the image I need to gather some analytics, like:

```
- http referrer
- IP of the viewer
- time the picture was viewed
```

And then show it to the user on my website.

I was doing it all on my side (by simply saving every image view it to database), but now the servise is too big to maintain this data (that's like hundreds of records per day for every picture, times 50-70 pics per user, lots of data). So I'm thinking to find some powerful external service that can do that for me.

Maybe something like http://goo.gl (as it has pretty good stats per day/week/month/year, charts, everything is stored on Google servers, etc). But that one should be attached to gmail account, and I also don't think it supports simple export of that data. I also need to be able to get total stats for selected pictures, so that user doesn't have to click on each of them individually. Main thing is I want someone else to record and store the data. Don't mind paying a reasonable price.

Do you know any services like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Google has a Url Shortener API that does just what I need.